# -Roblox- How would I make an AI path finding bot that only moves on certain objects?

Tags: roblox

So currently I am making a game which involves guests like Coaster Tycoon 2...
I already have my AI script finished but I want to implement some more code so it only moves on parts named lets just say "Path". How would I go about doing this???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I suggest maybe making it so the guests are can collide mode then make it so that the player can't collide with anything other than solid objects. So put invisible walls along the paths and make it so the guest can't walk through them but the player can. Then do it so the guest when he hits a wall turns a different direction. Then script it so the players can walk through them walls.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've done this by using the A* pathfinding algorithm. You can modify the algorithm a bit so that the only nodes ever used are ones that fit your need (e.g. "Path" nodes). The ROBLOX Wiki has an [A* page](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=A*) with a good implementation of the method.